# Is there a better way to trim a DateTime to a specific precision?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

What's the best way to trim a DateTime object to a specific precision?  For instance, if I have a DateTime with a value of '2008-09-29 09:41:43', but I only want it's precision to be to the minute, is there any better way to do it than this?

```
private static DateTime TrimDateToMinute(DateTime date)
{
    return new DateTime(
        date.Year, 
        date.Month, 
        date.Day, 
        date.Hour, 
        date.Minute, 
        0);
}
```

What I would really want is to make it variable so that I could set its precision to the second, minute, hour, or day.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

```
static class Program
{
    //using extension method:
    static DateTime Trim(this DateTime date, long roundTicks)
    {
        return new DateTime(date.Ticks - date.Ticks % roundTicks, date.Kind);
    }

    //sample usage:
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Trim(TimeSpan.TicksPerDay));
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Trim(TimeSpan.TicksPerHour));
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Trim(TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond));
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Trim(TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute));
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Trim(TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

Comment: I like this very much and if I was using the 3.5 framework, this is the route I would take, unless there's something better still out there.  Unfortunately, I'm using 2.0 so I'll have to stick to your first answer.  Thanks!

Comment: If you're making it a general-purpose extension method, it's worth preserving the DateTimeKind (Unspecified/Utc/Local):

return new DateTime(date.Ticks - date.Ticks % roundTicks, date.Kind);

Comment: ... or a one-liner that also preserves the Kind property: d = d.AddTicks(-(d.Ticks + 30*TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond) % TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute);

Comment: @Joe thanks man, I came here to write the same comment after spending 2 hours debugging expired auth tokens :))

Answer (score 9):

You could use an enumeration

```
public enum DateTimePrecision
{
  Hour, Minute, Second
}

public static DateTime TrimDate(DateTime date, DateTimePrecision precision)
{
  switch (precision)
  {
    case DateTimePrecision.Hour:
      return new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, date.Hour, 0, 0);
    case DateTimePrecision.Minute:
      return new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, date.Hour, date.Minute, 0);
    case DateTimePrecision.Second:
      return new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, date.Hour, date.Minute, date.Second);
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

and expand as required.

Comment: For Hour and Minute, I'm wondering if Minutes and Seconds should be rounded than using 0?

Comment: Certainly you could adapt the code to round rather than truncate should you need to; often I find truncation feels more natural as that is effectively how clocks behave.

Comment: when you need it only once - return new DateTime(dt.Year, 1, 1)

Comment: Please remember to preserve the `DateTime.Kind`.

Answer (score 8):

I like this method. Someone mentioned it was good to preserve the Date Kind, etc. This accomplishes that because you dont have to make a new DateTime. The DateTime is properly cloned from the original DateTime and it simply subtracts the remainder ticks.

```
public static DateTime FloorTime(DateTime dt, TimeSpan interval) 
{
  return dt.AddTicks(-1 * (dt.Ticks % interval.Ticks));
}
```

usage:

```
dt = FloorTime(dt, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)); // floor to the nearest 5min interval
dt = FloorTime(dt, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)); // floor to the nearest second
dt = FloorTime(dt, TimeSpan.FromDays(1));    // floor to the nearest day
```

Comment: Since DateTime format is a structure (value type), any manipulation will create a new value even though it does not present it that way. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1859266/955444

Comment: True, but it is properly cloned by the DateTime code, so the time zone is indeed preserved. I will slightly reword my answer to be more clear. Thank you.

Comment: Suggestion: `-1 * (dt.Ticks % interval.Ticks)` can also be written as `- (dt.Ticks % interval.Ticks)`

Answer (score 1):

There are some good solutions presented here, but when I need to do this, I simply do:

```
DateTime truncDate;
truncDate = date.Date; // trim to day
truncDate = date.Date + TimeSpan.Parse(string.Format("{0:HH:00:00}", date)); // trim to hour
truncDate = date.Date + TimeSpan.Parse(string.Format("{0:HH:mm}", date)); // trim to minute
truncDate = date.Date + TimeSpan.Parse(string.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss}", date)); // trim to second
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: doesn't work, returns only the day + 00:00:00

Comment: @katz: I'm sorry, but I tested this solution when I published my reply and I have just tested it again and it works perfectly fine. Are you sure you're not testing only the first option above (trim to day)? I don't believe that all the TimeSpan.Parse method calls above are returning to you 00:00:00. Are you sure you're using a DIFFERENT variable (other than the variable "date" itself) to receive the results of these operations (as I used "truncDate" in my example)? If you use the "date" variable itself, the first operation above will truncate it to day, compromising all other results below.

Comment: @katz: Use a DIFFERENT variable (like "truncDate") and don't do ALL the operations above in sequence and THEN print the result. My code was just an example, but EACH operation (each code line) should be used separately, depending on the precision you want (day, hour, minute or second). For instance, try to execute only the LAST line (trim to second) and then print the result.

Comment: @katz: Sorry, in the "trim to hour" code line, the was an error, and I have just edited the code. It seems the string format "{0:HH}" does not return (as I would expect) the hour component of the date,so I changed it to "{0:HH:00:00}, which works fine. The other code lines are correct. And all the observations I made in the comments above are still valid.

Comment: Thanks for your support. With the changes everything is working :) +1

Comment: Instead of a Parse(), it's **much** faster to do `+ new TimeSpan(date.Hours, 0, 0)`

Answer (score -2):

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime()
dt = dt.AddSeconds(-dt.Second)
```

Above code will trim seconds.

Comment: It will not trim milliseconds and will result in bad `dt`.

Comment: Just add .AddMillisceconds() too then. This answer is suprerior to the other ones in my opinion, since it is way less boiler plate. But please correct me.