# Cut-/Rounding down a DateTime to a Whole i.e. Hour/Day?

Tags: c#

Is there any kind of mathematical way to cut DateTime down to a exact Hour, Day or so? Similiar to round of a decimal to int.

Period.Day 
If the original value was `2011-01-01 13:00:00`, it ends up in `2011-01-01 00:00:00`

if Period.Hour 
If the original value was `2011-03-11 13:32:00`, it ends up in `2011-03-11 13:00:00`

I think about something like below. This are of course works fine, but the `range`-array are iterated through anyway, later. Better if I was possible to calculate directly on that iteration, instead of it's own. But someType can't be put into that iteration (it depends on someType).

```
if (someType == Period.Day)
  range.ForEach(d => d.time = new DateTime(d.time.Year, d.time.Month, d.time.Day,0,0,0));
if (someType == Period.Hour)
  range.ForEach(d => d.time = new DateTime(d.time.Year, d.time.Month, d.time.Day, d.time.Hour, 0, 0));
```

Comment: Your examples don't round to the nearest. They truncate/round down.

Comment: Replace `ForEach` with `Select`?

Comment: @CodeInChaos You are completely right. I will change the title because it's missleading.

Comment: What about d.AddMinutes(-d.Minute) to round to minutes?

Comment: @VoidMain doesn't look right. You're setting the minutes to 0 with that, but keep seconds and fractions of a second.

Comment: Yes, and it requires a descision inside the loop `Are there minutes, hours or day I have to clear, here` (Period.Type)

Comment: You're righ @CodeInChaos but i was thinking among these lines, all the addXxxx in DateTime, return DateTime, you can chain it as much as you like and end up with something like this: d.AddHours( -d.Hour ).AddMinutes( -d.Minute ).AddSeconds( -d.Second ).AddMilliseconds( -d.Millisecond );

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Rounding down to a day is equivalent to `time.Date`, rounding to nearest (up on midpoint) is simply `( time + 12hours ).Date`.

For rounding down to a full hour I can't think of code that's nicer to read than yours. For rounding up to the nearest hour you can apply your code to `time + 30mins`.

There is probably a faster method for rounding to the nearest hour:

```
const Int64 HourInTicks=...;
Int64 timeInTicks=time.Ticks;
Int64 trucatedToHour=timeInTicks-timeInTicks%HourInTicks;
```

But I'd avoid that, unless you *really* need the performance, which is unlikely.

*(My round to nearest might have issues on days where the local time offset changes if you're using local time)*

Comment: Yes, very small performance difference between those good answers here. So I finally go to the most readable and clear way (because the functionality itself is a little obscure). I keep the foreach but through a "cleardate(date,period)"-method and immedietly after the data source. Which means the whole routine are already done by this loop.

Answer (score 19):

To round down to day you can use the [DateTime.Date Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx).
To round down to hour, I'm afraid you'll have to either use what you did in your example or something like:

```
d.Date.AddHours(d.Hour)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll do the following:

```
private static readonly DateTime Epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1); 
public static DateTime Round(this DateTime d, Period p)
{
    var ts = d - Epoch;

    if (p == Period.Hour)
    {
        var hours = (long)ts.TotalHours;
        return Epoch.AddHours(hours);
    }
    else if (p == Period.Days)
    {
        var days = (long)ts.TotalDays;
        return Epoch.AddDays(days);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the following C# code will round a DateTime value to nearest minute, and I think it will be easy to generalize it to round to other units.

```
//round to nearest minute; add 30 seconds for rounding to nearest minute
effectiveDateTime = effectiveDateTime.AddSeconds(30);
TimeSpan timeComponent = effectiveDateTime.TimeOfDay;
effectiveDateTime = effectiveDateTime.Date;
effectiveDateTime = effectiveDateTime.AddHours(timeComponent.Hours).
     AddMinutes(timeComponent.Minutes);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this approach is effective, but looks quite nice using string format (in this case cutting down to hours):

```
var date = DateTime.UtcNow;
var cutDownDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer [Is there a better way in C# to round a DateTime to the nearest 5 seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766626/is-there-a-better-way-in-c-sharp-to-round-a-datetime-to-the-nearest-5-seconds/4108889#4108889) contains an excellent generic `DateTime` rounding approach.

*Edit:* 
This answer was before the updated question title and is an algorithm for *rounding to nearest* not *rounding down*.

Comment: Oh, I looked at that (and just the accepted answer). A nice feature from Matt W. It solve my question completely together with a little modification. RoundOff with TimeSpan.FromTicks(X). I get the ticks from Period.Month / Period.Days and whola, the call is generic! Though it does not provide any performance from my own sample that done double iteration. Developing are sometimes so erratic.. :)

Answer (score -1):

Best method for day:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime roundDay = now.Date;
```