# Round Down to nearest boundary in dateTime

Tags: c#, algorithm, datetime

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4108889/544716) of a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766626/is-there-a-better-way-in-c-sharp-to-round-a-datetime-to-the-nearest-5-seconds/4108889#4108889) the DateTime is rounded to the closes (time) boundary, 
the `Math.Round` method does not allow round to the lower boundary by choice.
Is there a way to calculate the same way the lower boundary of some time ?
Meaning if the time is 10/2/2012 10:52:30 and the choice is an hour than the time is :  10/2/2012 10:00:00, if the choice is day than 10/2/2012 00:00:00 and so on.

Comment: Are you planning to use your `DateTime` value in arithmetic later on or just display it rounded?

Comment: Yes, i would use it in an sql query

Comment: Then you likely need a string anyway. Why not just use a variation of @JonSkeet's answer or just `DateTime.ToString()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only need to go to a particular unit, I probably wouldn't even bother using `Math.Round` or `Math.Floor` - I'd just go with something like:

```
switch (unitToRoundDownTo)
{
    case Unit.Second:
        return new DateTime(old.Year, old.Month, old.Day,
                            old.Hour, old.Minute, old.Second, old.Kind);
    case Unit.Minute:
        return new DateTime(old.Year, old.Month, old.Day,
                            old.Hour, old.Minute, 0, old.Kind);
    case Unit.Hour:
        return new DateTime(old.Year, old.Month, old.Day, old.Hour, 0, 0, old.Kind);
    case Unit.Day:
        return new DateTime(old.Year, old.Month, old.Day, 0, 0, 0, old.Kind);
    case Unit.Month:
        return new DateTime(old.Year, old.Month, 1, 0, 0, 0, old.Kind);
    case Unit.Year:
        return new DateTime(old.Year, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, old.Kind);
    default:
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
}
```

That doesn't work if you need "the nearest 5 minutes" etc, but for a single time unit it's simpler to understand and debug than trying to get arithmetic to work.

Alternatively, as a different spin on the *accepted* answer to the question you link to, you can just do:

```
// tickCount is the rounding interval, e.g. TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5).Ticks
DateTime rounded = new DateTime((old.Ticks / tickCount) * tickCount);
```

Note that this won't help for rounding to the start of the month or year.

Comment: It's probably a good idea to maintain the kind as well, which you can accomplish by adding `, old.Kind` as the final parameter to the DateTime constructor.

Comment: @Brad: Yes, that's true. Will edit. (Not that I'm keen on the kind part, but...)

Answer (score 3):

Try `Math.Floor` instead of `Math.Round` (in a similar fashion to the post you linked).