# Added Datime specific offset

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, .net-core

I have a big list of different **DateTime** field.
Then need converting date by specified range, *for instance* (this condition):

```
var startDate = new DateTime(2021, 2, 1, 0, 00, 00, DateTimeKind.Utc);
var endDate = new DateTime(2021, 5, 1, 0, 0, 00, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

Then I added offset to my dateTime

```
    ...
var offset = dateTime!.Value.Subtract(firstCandleTimestamp);
return candles.Select(mc => { mc.Timestamp = mc.Timestamp.Add(offset); return mc; });
    ...
```

But i have some important property **periodSeond** to that convert my date. For example i converting my date to range by condition upper

- {Timestamp: 01/02/2021 12:00:00 am}
- {Timestamp: 01/02/2021 1:00:00 am}
- {Timestamp: 01/02/2021 2:00:00 am}

But I need change my date and return by period.
For exmaple periodSecond = 180 sec (= 3min)

- {Timestamp: 01/02/2021 12:**03**:00 am}
- {Timestamp: 01/02/2021 1:**06**:00 am}
- {Timestamp: 01/02/2021 2:**09**:00 am}

or periodSeond = 86400( = 1day)

- {Timestamp: **01**/02/2021 00:00:00 am}
- {Timestamp: **02**/02/2021 00:00:00 am}
- {Timestamp: **03**/02/2021 00:00:00 am}

etc... Need change datetime by this scenario.

Comment: For rounding DateTime check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766626/is-there-a-better-way-in-c-sharp-to-round-a-datetime-to-the-nearest-5-seconds)

Comment: Why does 180 second get added to first Timestamp, but 86400 second does not get added to first Timestamp?

Comment: @NetMage because I need do different scenario, it is so exmaple. I need add various time (1m, 3, 5m, 60m, 1h, 1d, 1week, ...).

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Your example is inconsistent. You don't treat 1 day the same as 3 min.

Comment: @NetMage I'll want to change dateTime by specified period, if set 3 min - period, need change every date +3 min to each.