# DateTime inserted in SqlServer changes value

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

When I insert these values

```
09/30/2013 05:04:56.599 
09/30/2013 05:04:56.599
09/30/2013 05:04:56.599
09/30/2013 05:04:57.082
```

in SqlServer database, the millisecond value changes in a weird way

```
2013-09-30 05:04:56.600 
2013-09-30 05:04:56.600 
2013-09-30 05:04:56.600 
2013-09-30 05:04:57.083
```

What's wrong ?

Edit:
Relevant code:

```
        com = new SqlCommand();
        com.Connection = con;
        com.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [AuthSourceTimings]
                                   ([FileName]
                                   ,[JobID]
                                   ,[JobCreationTime]
                                   ,[JobSendTime]
                                   ,[JobAckTime]
                                   ,[JobDoneTime])
                             VALUES
                                   (@FileName
                                   ,@JobID
                                   ,@JobCreationTime
                                   ,@JobSendTime
                                   ,@JobAckTime
                                   ,@JobDoneTime)
                            ";

        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", fileName);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobID", t.JobID);

        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobCreationTime", t.JobCreationTime == DateTime.MinValue ? (object)DBNull.Value : (object)t.JobCreationTime);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobSendTime", t.JobSendTime == DateTime.MinValue ? (object)DBNull.Value : (object)t.JobSendTime);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobAckTime", t.JobAcknowledgementTime == DateTime.MinValue ? (object)DBNull.Value : (object)t.JobAcknowledgementTime);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobDoneTime", t.JobCompletionTime == DateTime.MinValue ? (object)DBNull.Value : (object)t.JobCompletionTime);

        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: good question +1, can you post the code from where you are sending it to db?

Comment: Use datetime2 if you are using sql server 2008 or plus 
Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823966/milliseconds-in-my-datetime-changes-when-stored-in-sql-server

Comment: +1 because this question generated multiple good answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Milliseconds are stored only with precision of about 1/300th of a second in datetime format so that's where the inaccuracy comes from.

You can check this answer: [Why is SQL Server losing a millisecond?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715432/why-is-sql-server-losing-a-millisecond)

To get higher precision (100 nanoseconds), you can use `DATETIME2` which was introduced in SQL Server 2008. You can get more information here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx
- http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1616/sql-server-2008-date-and-time-data-types/

Answer (score 5):

You are probably using the SQL Server type `DATETIME`, which the documentation states:

```
Rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds.
```

The `DATETIME2` type should be used if you want full compatibility with .NET `DateTime`. Both of these have an accuracy of 100 nanoseconds.

There aren't many good reasons to use `DATETIME` anymore. A `DATETIME2(7)` takes up 8 bytes which is the same as a `DATETIME`, but has a far greater accuracy and range. A `DATETIME2(3)` takes up 6 bytes and still has better accuracy (3 decimals without the weird rounding behavior detailed above).

Answer (score 1):

Its alll about precision. If you are using datetime type in database, try datetime2 type.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your table's structure. In the `create table` part, it should be like this:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (dt DATETIME(6) NOT NULL);
```

To get the [Output](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9086/1/0) as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty Clear that it is not the `.NET` or code issue

```
DECLARE @TestDateFrom  DATETIME='2010-06-29 05:04:56.599'
SELECT @TestDateFrom
```

Result

**2010-06-29 05:04:56.600**

And Satisfied with Szymon answer *"Milliseconds are stored only with precision of about 1/300th of a second in datetime format so that's where the inaccuracy comes from."*