# EF DateTimes do not match saved values in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, datetime

I save a datetime using C# Entity Framework, and when I load that time back from the database, the time varies from the value that I saved by 1 or more milliseconds.

Here is the C# Code:

```
    public List<DateTime> TestDate()
    {
        var dates = new List<DateTime>();
        DateTime testvalue = DateTime.Now;
        dates.Add(testvalue);
        IactexGMG2Entities firstContext = new IactexGMG2Entities();
        var firstQuery = from p in firstContext.LocationProperties
                         where p.locationPropertyId == 4
                         select p;
        var firstRec = firstQuery.Single();
        firstRec.locationPropertyDateTime = testvalue;
        firstContext.SaveChanges();
        firstContext.Dispose();
         IactexGMG2Entities secondContext = new IactexGMG2Entities();
         var secondQuery = from p in secondContext.LocationProperties
                          where p.locationPropertyId == 4
                          select p;
        var secondRec = secondQuery.Single();

        var secondDate = secondRec.locationPropertyDateTime ?? DateTime.Now;
        dates.Add(secondDate);
        secondContext.Dispose();
        return dates;
    }
```

Here are the received values:

```
5/29/2015 5:43:25 PM . 154 , 635685182051540566
5/29/2015 5:43:25 PM . 153 , 635685182051530000
```

Here is the razor code that displays the values:

```
@foreach (var date in Model)
{
    counter++;
    <div>
        @date . @date.Millisecond , @date.Ticks 
    </div>
}
```

As you can see, the second value, which was read back from the database, is lower than the first value by 1.0566 milliseconds.

The amount of variation varies, positive and negative, always with a small number of milliseconds.

Does anyone know how the conversion between the date values takes place?

**Note:** If I use the same context to read the date value, the values match.  I assume that is because it is using the cached value, rather than the SQL Server value.

Comment: What is the data-type of the column in SQL Server? SQL Server's `datetime` type does not offer the same resolution as `System.DateTime`.

Comment: Where are the milisecond values coming from? If you're storing `DateTime.Now` (or `DateTime.UtcNow`) in the database consider rounding them to the nearest second before saving them.

Comment: Have you looked at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823966/milliseconds-in-my-datetime-changes-when-stored-in-sql-server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is the different resolution between TSQL [datetime](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) and .NET [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) data types

datetime only has a small resolution and is rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds, whereas DateTime has a resultion of 100ns

Just use the new [datetime2](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) SQL Data Type, which has the same resolution as .NET's DateTime, which is anyway recommended in new work, exactly for the issue you noticed

Answer (score 3):

This actually has very little to nothing to do with Entity Framework.  SQL Server as of 2008 has two DateTime types:

[DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx)

> Accuracy : Rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds

[DateTime2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx)

> Accuracy : 100 nanoseconds

Using Code-First Annotations you can set the property type like:

```
public MyClass
{
    [Column(“CreatedOn", TypeName="DateTime2")] 
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

Or using Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyClass>()
  .Property(p => p.CreatedOn)
  .HasColumnType("DateTime2");
```