# Insert DateTime with milliseconds into SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, npoco

I started a new ASP.NET MVC project two weeks ago. I'm using the micro ORM NPoco and I love it!

During testing I ran into a problem saving `DateTime` properties into SQL Server 2014 Express.

When I tried to insert the `DateTime` value `00:03:28.385` it saved in the database as `00:03:28.387`. The database column type is `time(7)`. I tried `datetime2(7)` and the result is always the same -> 00:03:28.387

Then I tried the plain `System.Data.SqlClient`:

```
var insert = "insert into Foo(time) values (@time)";
var conn = new SqlConnection(@"conntionString");
conn.Open();
var cmd = new SqlCommand(insertString.ToString(), _conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time",  DateTime.ParseExact("00:03:28.385", "HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The result was the same: `00:03:28.387`

It would worked when insert the time as a string.

```
insert into Foo(time) values ('00:03:28.385')
```

So it’s not a problem from NPoco.

Comment: "@Time" in cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue starts with capital 'T' but in your string, it starts with lower case 't'. could this be the issue?

Comment: From the code and examples it looks like you are inserting time only and not date & time...

Comment: Probably you shouldn't be using `addwithvalue` and be explicit about parameter datatype.

Comment: I suspect it is because the line, `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time",`... passes a DateTime to the parameter.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you **properly** specify the parameters for your `SqlCommand`, it works just fine:

```
string connStr = "server=.;database=Test;Integrated security=SSPI;";
string insertQry = "INSERT INTO dbo.Foo(time) VALUES(@Time);";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
using (SqlCommand insertCmd = new SqlCommand(insertQry, conn))
{
    // use proper Parameters syntax - specify SqlDbType!
    insertCmd.Parameters.Add("@time", SqlDbType.Time).Value = TimeSpan.Parse("00:03:28.385");

    conn.Open();
    insertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

I think the `.AddParameterWithValue` might just *guess* the datatype wrong and use `SqlDbType.DateTime` which corresponds to the `DATETIME` type in SQL Server - and that does have a 3.33ms accuracy - so .385 would be "rounded up" to .387 for that datatype.

Comment: Thanks @marc_s! I just figured out that time (SQL Server) and TimeSpan (.NET) are working perfect together. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know all the details, but see Otiel's answer on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823966/milliseconds-in-my-datetime-changes-when-stored-in-sql-server). It seems to match what you are seeing.

[Milliseconds in my DateTime changes when stored in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823966/milliseconds-in-my-datetime-changes-when-stored-in-sql-server)

> This is due to the precision of the SQL datetime type. According to
> msdn:
>
> ```
> Datetime values are rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds
> ```

Comment: They say they are using `time(7)` datatype. Though does look like it is getting converted to that somewhere.

Comment: This doesn't apply because the OP is using a time data type and specifying a precision of 7. This would be correct if the OP was using the DateTime datatype: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: Note that so far this should be comment/vote to close as duplicate. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297804/summer-time-is-it-still-acceptable-to-close-as-duplicate

Comment: jac: I think it affects time, date, datetime2, and datetimeoffset in SQL Server: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx

Comment: Thanks for all your answers! T

Comment: Thanks! I basically change the DateTime data type to TimeSpan because I’m just interest at the time with milliseconds and time (SQL Server) <-> TimeSpan (.NET) works perfect together! Thanks again! Cheers, Stefan