# When converting string to datetime the milliseconds precision is changing

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to convert a string to datetime like this `select CONVERT(datetime, '31-05-2022 04:00:00.105', 105)` but the precision of the milliseconds changes. How is it possible ?

In my case it gives me `2022-05-31 04:00:00.107`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: See [Rounding of datetime fractional second precision](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#rounding-of-datetime-fractional-second-precision).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Datetime is only accurate to 3.33 milliseconds.  If you try to wedge a value in that is more precise than that, MS SQL will round to the near acceptable value.  More information is available here:

[Milliseconds in my DateTime changes when stored in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823966/milliseconds-in-my-datetime-changes-when-stored-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 2):

You could try the 'datetime2' (or 'datetimeoffset') column type to account for the greater precision required

```
select CONVERT(datetime2, '31-05-2022 04:00:00.105', 105)
```