# Is there a simple function for rounding a DateTime down to the nearest 30 minutes, in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime

For example:

2011-08-11 16:59 becomes 2011-08-11 16:30

Comment: There is no such function in the base class libraries.

Comment: There is no such function available

You can refer to : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029353/c-sharp-round-up-time-to-nearest-x-minutes][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029353/c-sharp-round-up-time-to-nearest-x-minutes

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393696/c-sharp-rounding-datetime-objects

Comment: Not a bad question. But why you people voted-down.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would say something like that

```
var time = DateTime.Now;
var rounded = time.AddMinutes(
        time.Minute>30 ? -(time.Minute-30) : -time.Minute)
```

And you could even do your own extension

```
public static class TimeHelper {
   public static DateTime RoundDown (this DateTime time)
   {
       return time.AddMinutes(
         time.Minute>30 ? -(time.Minute-30) : -time.Minute);
   }
}
```

**EDIT**

This function cut's also the seconds / milliseconds if necessary. Thanks for the hint.

```
public static DateTime RoundDown(this DateTime time)
{
    return time.Subtract(
        new TimeSpan(0, 0, time.Minute > 30 ? (time.Minute - 30) : time.Minute, 
            time.Second, time.Millisecond));
}
```

Comment: As written, 'Minutes' does not compile - there is no 'Minutes' property on the `DateTime` type. Changing to 'Minute' it compiles, but since the `Minute` property is an `int` the seconds will remain in the rounded result rather than truncating to the whole minute mark as the OP desires.

Answer (score 22):

```
DateTime RoundDown(DateTime dt, TimeSpan d)
{
    return new DateTime((dt.Ticks / d.Ticks) * d.Ticks);
}
```

*Example:*

```
var dt1 = RoundDown(DateTime.Parse("2011-08-11 16:59"), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
// dt1 == {11/08/2011 16:30:00}

var dt2 = RoundDown(DateTime.Parse("2011-08-11 17:00"), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
// dt2 == {11/08/2011 17:00:00}

var dt3 = RoundDown(DateTime.Parse("2011-08-11 17:01"), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
// dt3 == {11/08/2011 17:00:00}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you see any rounding problems with this? I am trying to RoundDown to the nearest minute and am randomly getting two different answers for the same interval.

Answer (score 4):

A more generic solution rounding to the nearest time span:

```
public static DateTime RoundUp(this DateTime dt, TimeSpan d)
{
    var delta = (d.Ticks - (dt.Ticks % d.Ticks)) % d.Ticks;
    return new DateTime(dt.Ticks + delta);
}

public static DateTime RoundDown(this DateTime dt, TimeSpan d)
{
    var delta = dt.Ticks % d.Ticks;
    return new DateTime(dt.Ticks - delta);
}

public static DateTime RoundToNearest(this DateTime dt, TimeSpan d)
{
    var delta = dt.Ticks % d.Ticks;
    bool roundUp = delta > d.Ticks / 2;

    return roundUp ? dt.RoundUp(d) : dt.RoundDown(d);
}
```

It would be used this way:

```
var date = new DateTime(2010, 02, 05, 10, 35, 25, 450); // 2010/02/05 10:35:25
var rounded = date.RoundToNearest(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)); // 2010/02/05 10:30:00
```

More in [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20046261/469218).

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime newDateTime = new DateTime(oldDateTime.Year, oldDateTime.Month, oldDateTime.Day
  ,oldDateTime.Hour, (oldDateTime.Minute / 30) * 30, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Exploiting some math

```
var input = DateTime.Now; // or however you get DateTime
var rounded = input.AddMinutes(-input.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes % 30d);
```

Note that `TimeOfDay` is a `TimeSpan` and its `TotalMinutes` property is a `double` and that the modulus operator functions on doubles like follows:

> 47.51 % 30d == 17.51
>
> 16.2 % 30d == 16.2
>
> 768.7 % 30d == 18.7

You could change the 30d to any value you like other than zero. Changing to 15 rounds down to 15 minute intervals for instance. Changing from 30d to -30d, didn't change the results from the tests that I ran.

You could create a rounding extension method (providing this rounding method for all DateTime values):

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static DateTime Round(this DateTime self, double minutesInInterval)
    {
        if (minutesInInterval == 0d) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("minutesInInterval");
        return self.AddMinutes(-self.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes % minutesInInterval);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function available

You can refer to : [How can I round up the time to the nearest X minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029353/c-sharp-round-up-time-to-nearest-x-minutes)

IF needed you can create one yourself

```
DateTime RoundUp(DateTime dt, TimeSpan d)
{
   return new DateTime(((dt.Ticks - d.Ticks + 1) / d.Ticks) * d.Ticks + d.Ticks);
}
```

eg:

```
var dt1 = RoundUp(DateTime.Parse("2011-08-11 16:59"), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
// dt1 == {11/08/2011 16:30:00}
```

Comment: sad but his nearest 30 min is `16:30`

Comment: @V4Vendetta my bad. fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I handled it. Below is the base method and an overload to round to the nearest 30 minutes:

```
public static DateTime RoundMinutes(this DateTime value)
{
    return RoundMinutes(value, 30);
}

public static DateTime RoundMinutes(this DateTime value, int roundMinutes)
{
    DateTime result = new DateTime(value.Ticks);

    int minutes = value.Minute;
    int hour = value.Hour;
    int minuteMod = minutes % roundMinutes;

    if (minuteMod <= (roundMinutes / 2))
    {
        result = result.AddMinutes(-minuteMod);
    }
    else
    {
        result = result.AddMinutes(roundMinutes - minuteMod);
    }

    return result;
}
```