# DotNet Roundoff datetime to last 15 minutes

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a function to round off the datetime to last quarter?

Example...

```
08:03:00 becomes 08:00:00

08:14:00 becomes 08:00:00

08:15:00 stays   08:15:00

08:16:00 becomes 08:15:00

08:29:00 becomes 08:15:00

08:45:00 stays   08:45:00 

08:55:00 becomes 08:45:00

09:01:00 becomes 09:00:00
```

I have written the below function, **but it returns the next quarter** ...

```
private DateTime RoundUpToPreviousQuarter(DateTime date, TimeSpan d)
{
      return new DateTime(((date.Ticks + d.Ticks - 1) / d.Ticks) * d.Ticks);
}

// call the method
this.RoundUp(time, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15));
```

Any inputs appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apply the modulo 15 to the datetime Minute property and subtract that value from the same property

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2013,5,28, 15, 59,0);
dt = dt.AddMinutes(-(dt.Minute % 15));
```

In this example I have created a zero seconds datetime. If you need to remove also the seconds

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2013,5,28, 15, 59,45);
dt = dt.AddMinutes(-(dt.Minute % 15)).AddSeconds(-dt.Second);
```

Comment: And what about seconds? They will stay the same, I doubt that OP wanted such round-down.

Comment: Seconds not required. Only minutes.

Answer (score 3):

Change you method to:

```
private DateTime RoundUpToPreviousQuarter(DateTime date, TimeSpan d)
{
    return new DateTime(((date.Ticks) / d.Ticks) * d.Ticks);
}
```

Checked this it works for me.

Comment: Will fail for 08:45:00

Comment: This contains an Off By One bug. Should be `(date.Ticks / d.Ticks) * d.Ticks`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10100259

Comment: @SergeyS Changed now such that it doesn't fail for 08:45:00

Comment: Why is the method called RoundUpToPREVIOUSQUARTER if the method accepts a variable TimeSpan to round to?  Something like RoundUp would be a more suitable name