# expire cache at specific time

Tags: c#, caching

I am using `cache.insert()` method to add some data to cache, and it uses absolute expiration and expires once in 4 hours. 
Now I have a new requirement to expire the cache in specific times: 7am, 11am, 3pm, 7pm.

Is there a way to do it?

Current code:

```
ctx.Cache.Insert("stmodel", stModel, null,
                 DateTime.Now.AddHours(4), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Default, OnCachedItemRemoved);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are looking for [Rounding DateTime objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393696/rounding-datetime-objects)

Comment: How does rounding Datetime will help in this requirement?

Comment: Isn't your question "how to find next moment in time rounded up to 4hours"? (also simple `if` with 4 conditions may be enough and more readable than rounding suggested in that post `DateTime.Now.AddHours(4) < DateTime.Today.AddHours(7) ? DateTime.Today.AddHours(7) : ...` )

Comment: Just replace the DateTime.Now.AddHours with a method that returns the specific time. For example, you can call it GetNewExpiryTime. If it's greater than 7am and less then 11am, return today at 11am, etc, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ctx.Cache.Insert("stmodel", stModel, null,
             MyClass.getSpecificDateTime(), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Default, OnCachedItemRemoved);

 public static DateTime getSpecificDateTime()
    {
        TimeSpan currentTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
        DateTime newTime = DateTime.Now;

        if (currentTime.Hours < 7){
            newTime = newTime.Date + new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0);
        }else if (currentTime.Hours < 11){
            newTime = newTime.Date + new TimeSpan(11, 0, 0);
        }else if (currentTime.Hours < 15) {
            newTime = newTime.Date + new TimeSpan(15, 0, 0);
        }else if (currentTime.Hours < 19){
            newTime = newTime.Date + new TimeSpan(19, 0, 0);
        }else {
            newTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
            newTime = newTime.Date + new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0);
        }   

        return newTime;
    }
```