# Determine if one TimeSpan falls into another time span intervals

Tags: c#, datetime, datetimepicker

I have a `TimeSpan` variable that can be some time like `10:00:00` or some time like 10:23:00
And also I have another `TimeSpan` variable that is used to set the time interval, currently as default it is set on one hour intervals so `1:00:00`

I am looking for a good way to determine if my timespan variable falls into my interval or not? For example if interval is every one hour then `10:00:00` is ok because we have hours or 1,2,3,4,5,etc.. but `10:23:00` is not ok because we have `10` and `11` but not `10:23`

Is there any built in .NET way to determine this? if there is not then what is a good way to determine this.

Comment: `TimeSpan` describes durations that do not start and end at specific times. So how can one `TimeSpan` fall into another one? You need either two `DateTime` structures (for start and end) or one `DateTime` and one `TimeSpan` structure (for start and duration).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this will fit your needs. Keep in mind that it checks to the exact tick (1/10000th of a second).

```
static bool IsAtExactInterval(TimeSpan value, TimeSpan interval)
{
    long remainder = value.Ticks % interval.Ticks;

    return remainder == 0;        
}

Assert.IsTrue(IsAtExactInterval(new TimeSpan(10, 0, 0), new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0)));
Assert.IsFalse(IsAtExactInterval(new TimeSpan(10, 23, 0), new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0)));
```

When dealing with `TimeSpan`s that are generated with the current date and time (such as `DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay`), you might want to round the value first:

```
static TimeSpan Round(TimeSpan value, TimeSpan valueToRoundTo)
{
    long factor = (value.Ticks + (valueToRoundTo.Ticks / 2) + 1) / valueToRoundTo.Ticks;

    return new TimeSpan(factor * valueToRoundTo.Ticks);
}

TimeSpan value = new TimeSpan(10, 0, 25);
TimeSpan oneMinute = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);

TimeSpan roundedValue = Round(value, oneMinute);

Assert.IsTrue(new TimeSpan(10, 0, 0), roundedValue);

Assert.IsTrue(IsAtExactInterval(roundedValue, new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0)));
```

Via: [Rounding DateTime objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393696/rounding-datetime-objects)

Answer (score 3):

Your function requires a start time, as a datetime, an interval, and then a datetime to test.  To see if the test value is some multiple of the given interval with respect to the given start time, you can simply compute a timespan between the current and start time, and see if the remainder of those ticks when divided by the interval is zero.

```
public static bool IsOnTick(DateTime start, TimeSpan interval, 
    DateTime dateToTest)
{
    return (dateToTest - start).Ticks % interval.Ticks == 0;
}
```