# Round off dateTimePicker value

Tags: c#, datetimepicker, datetime-format

I am calculating the difference between `dateTimePicker2` and `dateTimePicker1` and converting it to minutes as this,

```
durinmin = Convert.ToInt32((dateTimePicker2.Value - dateTimePicker1.Value).TotalMinutes);
```

Problem is, for example if the difference value is "00:17:40", the `durinmin = 18`. But I want to hold the value of only completed minutes, i.e., `durinmin=17` is the value I want my program to consider. How to get it?

Comment: I wouldn't expect that behaviour. Please post a short but complete example - noting that `DateTimePicker.Value` just returns a `DateTime`, so you can easily write a [mcve] which *doesn't* use `DateTimePicker`, and just hard-codes two `DateTime` values. (Console apps make for great short examples...)

Comment: Please refer to this similar thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393696/rounding-datetime-objects Regards.

Comment: Interesting close-vote: _Off topic, not about programming_. Ehh..?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having said that I wouldn't expect that behaviour, I've just noticed that [`Convert.ToInt32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ffdk7eyz(v=vs.110).aspx) rounds instead of truncating - so it's behaving exactly as expected. The `TotalMinutes` property is returning 17.6666 (etc) which is being rounded up to 18.

All you need to do is use a cast instead of the method - casting to `int` will truncate towards 0:

```
TimeSpan difference = dateTimePicker2.Value - dateTimePicker1.Value;
int minutes = (int) difference.TotalMinutes;
```

Answer (score 1):

just use `Math.Floor`

```
durinmin = (int)Math.Floor((dateTimePicker2.Value - dateTimePicker1.Value).TotalMinutes);
```

Comment: You don't need to use `Math.Floor` - just casting is enough. One difference here is that if the duration is *negative*, this will round down instead of rounding towards 0. It's not entirely clear what the OP would want in this case...

Comment: It's impossible to get negative duration in this case. coz, durinmin = (stop time - start time). But it's good to have your valuable suggestion.

Comment: Jon's answer is probably better as per above comment

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using TotalMinutes, use the Minutes property of the TimeSpan:

```
durinmin = Convert.ToInt32((dateTimePicker2.Value - dateTimePicker1.Value).Minutes);
```