# Rounding time in Nodatime to nearest interval

Tags: c#, nodatime

We need to floor a time to the nearest arbitrary interval (represented by e.g. a Timespan or a Duration).

Assume for an example that we need to floor it to the nearest ten minutes.
e.g. 13:02 becomes 13:00 and 14:12 becomes 14:10

Without using Nodatime you could do something like [this:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393696/rounding-datetime-objects)

```cs
// Floor
long ticks = date.Ticks / span.Ticks;
return new DateTime( ticks * span.Ticks );
```

Which will use the ticks of a timespan to floor a datetime to a specific time.

It seems NodaTime exposes some complexity we hadn't considered before. You can write a function like this:

```cs
public static Instant FloorBy(this Instant time, Duration duration)
=> time.Minus(Duration.FromTicks(time.ToUnixTimeTicks() % duration.BclCompatibleTicks));
```

But that implementation doesn't seem correct.
"Floor to nearest ten minutes" seems to be dependent on timezone/offset of the time.
While might be 13:02 in UTC, in Nepal which has an offset of +05:45, the time would be 18:47.

This means that in UTC, flooring to the nearest ten minutes, would mean subtracting two minutes, while in Nepal, it would mean subtracting seven minutes.

I feel like I should be able to round a ZonedDateTime or an OffsetDateTime by an arbitrary timespan somehow. I can get close by writing a function like this

```cs
public static OffsetDateTime FloorToNearestTenMinutes(this OffsetDateTime time)
{
    return time
        .Minus(Duration.FromMinutes(time.Minute % 10))
        .Minus(Duration.FromSeconds(time.Second));
}
```

but that doesn't allow me to specify an arbitrary duration, as the OffsetDateTime has no concept of ticks.

How do I round an Instant/ZonedDateTime/OffsetDateTime correctly, with an arbitrary interval, taking into account time zones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up taking some stuff from Jon Skeets answer and rolling my own Rounder that takes in an arbitrary Duration to round with. (Which was one of the key things I needed, which is also why I'm not accepting that answer).

Per Jons suggestion I convert the Instant to an OffsetDateTime and apply the rounder, which takes in an arbitrary duration. Example and implementation is below:

```cs
// Example of usage
public void Example()
{
    Instant instant = SystemClock.Instance.GetCurrentInstant();
    OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = instant.WithOffset(Offset.Zero);
    var transformedOffsetDateTime = offsetDateTime.With(t => RoundToDuration(t, Duration.FromMinutes(15)));
    var transformedInstant = transformedOffsetDateTime.ToInstant();
}

// Rounding function, note that it at most truncates to midnight at the day.
public static LocalTime RoundToDuration(LocalTime timeToTransform, Duration durationToRoundBy)
{
    var ticksInDuration = durationToRoundBy.BclCompatibleTicks;
    var ticksInDay = timeToTransform.TickOfDay;
    var ticksAfterRounding = ticksInDay % ticksInDuration;
    var period = Period.FromTicks(ticksAfterRounding);

    var transformedTime = timeToTransform.Minus(period);
    return transformedTime;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For `OffsetDateTime`, I'd advise you to write a `Func<LocalTime, LocalTime>` which is effectively an "adjuster" in Noda Time terminology. You can then just use the `With` method:

```cs
// This could be a static field somewhere - or a method, so you can use
// a method group conversion.
Func<LocalTime, LocalTime> adjuster =>
    new LocalTime(time.Hour, time.Minute - time.Minute % 10, 0);

// The With method applies the adjuster to just the time portion,
// keeping the date and offset the same.
OffsetDateTime rounded = originalOffsetDateTime.With(adjuster);
```

Note that this only works because your rounding will never change the date. If you need a version that can change date as well (e.g. rounding 23:58 to 00:00 of the next day) then you'd need to get the new `LocalDateTime` and construct a new `OffsetDateTime` with that `LocalDateTime` and the original offset. We don't have a convenience method for that, but it's just a matter of calling the constructor.

`ZonedDateTime` is *fundamentally* trickier due to the reasons you've given. Right now, Nepal doesn't observe DST - but it might do so in the future. Rounding near the DST boundary could take you into an ambiguous or even skipped time, potentially. That's why we don't provide a similar `With` method for `ZonedDateTime`. (In your case it isn't likely, although it's historically possibly... with date adjusters you could easily end up in this situation.)

What you could do is:

- Call `ZonedDateTime.ToOffsetDateTime`
- Round the `OffsetDateTime` as above
- Call `OffsetDateTime.InZone(zone)` to get back to a `ZonedDateTime`

You *could* then check that the offset of the resulting `ZonedDateTime` is the same as the original, if you wanted to detect weird cases - but you'd then need to decide what to actually do about them. The behaviour is fairly reasonable though - if you start with a `ZonedDateTime` with a time portion of (say) 01:47, you'll end up with a `ZonedDateTime` in the same time zone from 7 minutes earlier. It's *possible* that wouldn't be 01:40, if a transition occurred within the last 7 minutes... but I *suspect* you don't actually need to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested here is my implementation, which correctly accounts for the occasions we cross a day, and always rounds up (rather than floors):

```
public static class RoundingExtensions
{
    private static readonly Duration OneDay = Duration.FromDays(1);

    public static LocalTime RoundUpToDuration(this LocalTime localDateTime, Duration duration)
    {
        if (duration <= Duration.Zero) return localDateTime;

        var ticksInDuration = duration.BclCompatibleTicks;
        var ticksInDay = localDateTime.TickOfDay;
        var ticksAfterRounding = ticksInDay % ticksInDuration;
        if (ticksAfterRounding == 0) return localDateTime;

        // Create period to add ticks to get to next rounding.
        var period = Period.FromTicks(ticksInDuration - ticksAfterRounding);
        return localDateTime.Plus(period);
    }

    public static OffsetDateTime RoundUpToDuration(this OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime, Duration duration)
    {
        if (duration <= Duration.Zero) return offsetDateTime;
        
        var result = offsetDateTime.With(t => RoundUpToDuration(t, duration));
        if (OffsetDateTime.Comparer.Instant.Compare(offsetDateTime, result) > 0) result = result.Plus(OneDay);
        return result;
    }

    public static ZonedDateTime RoundUpToDuration(this ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime, Duration duration)
    {
        if (duration <= Duration.Zero) return zonedDateTime;

        var odt = zonedDateTime.ToOffsetDateTime().RoundUpToDuration(duration);
        return odt.InZone(zonedDateTime.Zone);
    } 
}
```