# How to change time in DateTime?

Tags: c#, datetime, time

How can I change only the time in my `DateTime` variable "s"?

```
DateTime s = some datetime;
```

Answer (score 740, accepted):

You can't change a DateTime value - it's immutable. However, you can change the variable to have a new value. The easiest way of doing that to change just the time is to create a TimeSpan with the relevant time, and use the DateTime.Date property:

```
DateTime s = ...;
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(10, 30, 0);
s = s.Date + ts;
```

`s` will now be the same date, but at 10.30am.

Note that `DateTime` disregards daylight saving time transitions, representing "naive" Gregorian time in both directions (see Remarks section in the [`DateTime` docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). The only exceptions are `.Now` and `.Today`: they retrieve current system time which reflects these events as they occur.

This is the kind of thing which motivated me to start the [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) project, which is now production-ready. Its `ZonedDateTime` type is made "aware" [by linking it to a `tz` database entry](http://nodatime.org/1.2.x/userguide/tzdb.html).

Comment: s.Date.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0)) should also work. Using it to null out time when checking between days.

Comment: @user295734: Why would you call `Add` providing a zero timespan? Your expression is equivalent to `s.Date`, but longer...

Comment: Forgot to correct it, realized it after i put it in the code, for setting to zero(what i was originally searching for). But i was just trying to show how to get a time set in one line, if not setting to 0.

Comment: If you have 2 `DateTime`s, (one for the date and one for the time) you can do this: `var result = date.Date + time.TimeOfDay;`

Comment: @ZacharyYates: Yes, although I'd argue that at that point your model is broken to start with, and `time` shouldn't be a `DateTime`. (I'd use Noda Time of course, but...)

Comment: @JonSkeet Agreed. Just pointing it out if someone has to work with a model that they can't change (like I did earlier today)

Answer (score 138):

Alright I'm diving in with my suggestion, an extension method:

```
public static DateTime ChangeTime(this DateTime dateTime, int hours, int minutes, int seconds, int milliseconds)
{
    return new DateTime(
        dateTime.Year,
        dateTime.Month,
        dateTime.Day,
        hours,
        minutes,
        seconds,
        milliseconds,
        dateTime.Kind);
}
```

Then call:

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.Now.ChangeTime(10,10,10,0);
```

It's important to note that this extension returns a **new** date object, so you can't do this:

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.Now;
myDate.ChangeTime(10,10,10,0);
```

But you can do this:

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.Now;
myDate = myDate.ChangeTime(10,10,10,0);
```

Comment: This is essentially the same as `Datetime.Today.Add(time.TimeOfDay)`. That's because internally, the constructor doesn't do any calendar-based corrections except accounting for a leap year for the date part. I.e. `DateTime` is a "naive" implementation in terms of Python's `datetime` module.

Answer (score 85):

```
s = s.Date.AddHours(x).AddMinutes(y).AddSeconds(z);
```

In this way you preserve your date, while inserting a new hours, minutes and seconds part to your liking.

Comment: @Webleeuw Of course, a remote possibility of an [ArgumentOutOfRangeException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception.aspx) depending upon the added values. Here's a [Pex](http://pexforfun.com/default.aspx?language=CSharp&sample=Y2k) puzzle that demonstrate this.

Comment: And depending on the use case, can also do `.AddMilliseconds()` if needed.

Comment: @lifebalance the Pex link no longer works, could you elaborate the problem?

Answer (score 57):

one liner

```
var date = DateTime.Now.Date.Add(new TimeSpan(4, 30, 0));
```

would bring back todays date with a time of 4:30:00, replace DateTime.Now with any date object

Answer (score 26):

DateTime is an immutable type, so you can't *change* it.

However, you can create a new DateTime instance based on your previous instance. In your case, it sounds like you need the Date property, and you can then add a TimeSpan that represents the time of day.

Something like this:

```
var newDt = s.Date + TimeSpan.FromHours(2);
```

Answer (score 23):

If you already have the time stored in another `DateTime` object you can use the `Add` method.

```
DateTime dateToUse = DateTime.Now();
DateTime timeToUse = new DateTime(2012, 2, 4, 10, 15, 30); //10:15:30 AM

DateTime dateWithRightTime = dateToUse.Date.Add(timeToUse.TimeOfDay);
```

The `TimeOfDay` property is a `TimeSpan` object and can be passed to the `Add` method. And since we use the `Date` property of the `dateToUse` variable we get just the date and add the time span.

Answer (score 21):

Simplest solution :

```
DateTime s = //some Datetime that you want to change time for 8:36:44 ;
s = new DateTime(s.Year, s.Month, s.Day, 8, 36, 44);
```

And if you need a specific Date and Time Format :

```
s = new DateTime(s.Year, s.Month, s.Day, 8, 36, 44).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 18):

You can assign an initial value to a new `DateTime` value in many different ways:

- **Extension Method**

Extension method `DateTime`

```
    public static DateTime ChangeTime(this DateTime dateTime, int hours, int minutes, int seconds = default, int milliseconds = default)
    {
        return new DateTime(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, dateTime.Day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds, dateTime.Kind);
    }
```

then using `ChangeTime`:

```
    DateTime datetime = DateTime.Now; //Your DateTime
    datetime = datetime.ChangeTime(12, 20, 10);
```

- **using the Add methods**

  ```
  DateTime datetime = DateTime.Now; //Your DateTime
  datetime = datetime.Date.AddHours(12).AddMinutes(20).AddSeconds(10);
  ```
- **using the Timespan**

  ```
  DateTime datetime = DateTime.Now; //Your DateTime
  datetime = datetime.Date.Add(new TimeSpan(12, 20, 10));
  ```
- **using initial value**

  ```
  DateTime datetime = DateTime.Now;
  datetime = new DateTime(datetime.Year, datetime.Month, datetime.Day, 12, 20, 10);
  ```

Comment: nice extension method

Comment: I was going to say "nice changetime() example :)" but DateTime has no ChangeTime method that I can find :(  Oh I see, you provided your own!!  OK , fair enough :)  Pity Microsoft didn't pull their finger out and provide something for setting time of day.

Answer (score 13):

```
DateTime ts = DateTime.Now;
ts = new DateTime ( ts.Year, ts.Month, ts.Day, 0, 0, 0 ) ;
Console.WriteLine ( "Today = " + ts.ToString("M/dd/yy HH:mm:ss") ) ;
```

Executed:
    Today = 9/04/15 00:00:00

Answer (score 9):

Adding .Date to your date sets it to midnight (00:00).

```
MyDate.Date
```

**Note** The equivavalent SQL is `CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, @MyDate))`

What makes this method so good is that it's both quick to type and easy to read. A bonus is that there is no conversion from strings.

I.e. To set today's date to 23:30, use:

```
DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours(23).AddMinutes(30)
```

You can of course replace DateTime.Now or MyDate with any date of your choice.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the importance of `.Date`! For whatever reason I didn't really grasp why that was needed when I read the accepted answer.

Comment: Best  and cleanest answer. Upvoted  and thumbed up 

Answer (score 8):

Happened upon this post as I was looking for the same functionality this could possibly do what the guy wanted. Take the original date and replace the time part

```
DateTime dayOpen = DateTime.Parse(processDay.ToShortDateString() + " 05:00 AM");
```

Answer (score 5):

Since `DateTime` is immutable, a new instance has to be created when a date component needs to be changed. Unfortunately, there is no built-in functionality to set individual components of a `DateTime` instance.

Using the following extension methods

```cs
public static DateTime SetPart(this DateTime dateTime, int? year, int? month, int? day, int? hour, int? minute, int? second)
{
    return new DateTime(
        year ?? dateTime.Year,
        month ?? dateTime.Month,
        day ?? dateTime.Day,
        hour ?? dateTime.Hour,
        minute ?? dateTime.Minute,
        second ?? dateTime.Second
    );
}

public static DateTime SetYear(this DateTime dateTime, int year)
{
    return dateTime.SetPart(year, null, null, null, null, null);
}

public static DateTime SetMonth(this DateTime dateTime, int month)
{
    return dateTime.SetPart(null, month, null, null, null, null);
}

public static DateTime SetDay(this DateTime dateTime, int day)
{
    return dateTime.SetPart(null, null, day, null, null, null);
}

public static DateTime SetHour(this DateTime dateTime, int hour)
{
    return dateTime.SetPart(null, null, null, hour, null, null);
}

public static DateTime SetMinute(this DateTime dateTime, int minute)
{
    return dateTime.SetPart(null, null, null, null, minute, null);
}

public static DateTime SetSecond(this DateTime dateTime, int second)
{
    return dateTime.SetPart(null, null, null, null, null, second);
}
```

you can set individual `DateTime` components like

```cs
var now = DateTime.Now;

now.SetSecond(0);
```

Answer (score 4):

When you construct your `DateTime` object, use a constructor that allows you to specify time:

```
var myDateTime = new DateTime(2000, 01, 01, 13, 37, 42);  // 2000-01-01 13:37:42
```

If you already have a `DateTime` object and wish to change the time, uou can add minutes, hours or seconds to your `DateTime` using simple methods:

```
var myDateTime = new DateTime(2000, 01, 01);              // 2000-01-01 00:00:00
myDateTime = myDateTime.AddHours(13);                     // 2000-01-01 13:00:00
myDateTime = myDateTime.AddMinutes(37);                   // 2000-01-01 13:37:00
myDateTime = myDateTime.AddSecounds(42);                  // 2000-01-01 13:37:42
```

Notice how we have to "save" the result from each method call to the `myDateTime` variable. This is because the `DateTime` is immutable, and its methods simply create new instances with the extra hours/minutes/seconds added.

If you need to add both hours and minutes (and/or seconds) and the same time, you can simplify the code by adding a `TimeSpan` to the original `DateTime` instead:

```
var myDateTime = new DateTime(2000, 01, 01);              // 2000-01-01 00:00:00
myDateTime += new TimeSpan(13, 37, 42);                   // 2000-01-01 13:37:42
```

If you want to set absolute hours/minues/seconds, rather than adding to the existing values, you can use the aforementioned `DateTime` constructor, and reuse values for year/month/day from earlier:

```
myDateTime = new DateTime(myDateTime.Year, myDateTime.Month, myDateTime.Day,
                          20, 33, 19)                     // 2000-01-01 20:33:19
```

Comment: Add and subtract by using the AddXXX methods

Answer (score 4):

In fact, you can't change the time once it's created.
But you can create it easily with many constructors:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2

For example, if you want to create a DateTime changing Seconds, you can just do this:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime secondschanged = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, now.Hour, now.Minute, yourseconds);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a DateTime like 2014/02/05 18:19:51 and want just 2014/02/05, you can do that:

```
_yourDateTime = new DateTime(_yourDateTime.Year, _yourDateTime.Month, _yourDateTime.Day)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Date.Add` and add a `New TimeSpan` with the new time you want to add

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now
dt.Date.Add(new TimeSpan(12,15,00))
```

Answer (score 3):

To set end of a day:

```
date = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, 23, 59, 59);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int year = 2012;
int month = 12;
int day = 24;
int hour = 0;
int min = 0;
int second = 23;
DateTime dt = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, min, second);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method you could use to do it for you, use it like this

```
DateTime newDataTime = ChangeDateTimePart(oldDateTime, DateTimePart.Seconds, 0);
```

Here is the method, there is probably a better way, but I just whipped this up:

```
public enum DateTimePart { Years, Months, Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds };
public DateTime ChangeDateTimePart(DateTime dt, DateTimePart part, int newValue)
{
    return new DateTime(
        part == DateTimePart.Years ? newValue : dt.Year,
        part == DateTimePart.Months ? newValue : dt.Month,
        part == DateTimePart.Days ? newValue : dt.Day,
        part == DateTimePart.Hours ? newValue : dt.Hour,
        part == DateTimePart.Minutes ? newValue : dt.Minute,
        part == DateTimePart.Seconds ? newValue : dt.Second
        );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just come across this post because I had a similar issue whereby I wanted to set the time for an Entity Framework object in MVC that gets the date from a view (datepicker) so the time component is 00:00:00 but I need it to be the current time. Based on the answers in this post I came up with:

```
myEntity.FromDate += DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//The fastest way to copy time            

DateTime justDate = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1); // 1/1/2011 12:00:00AM the date you will be adding time to, time ticks = 0
DateTime timeSource = new DateTime(1999, 2, 4, 10, 15, 30); // 2/4/1999 10:15:30AM - time tick = x

justDate = new DateTime(justDate.Date.Ticks + timeSource.TimeOfDay.Ticks);

Console.WriteLine(justDate); // 1/1/2011 10:15:30AM
Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  DateTime s;
//s = datevalue
                s = s.AddMilliseconds(10);
                s = s.AddMinutes(10);
                s = s.AddSeconds(10);
                s = s.AddHours(10);
```

you could add +ve/-ve values in parameter.

```
s.Add(new TimeSpan(1, 1, 1));
```

Comment: @Jon: I commented the line. the user need to assign some value before using this code.

Comment: @Saar: More importantly, you've *now* added the assignments back to s (except for the call to s.Add(...)).

Comment: @Jon: I learned my lesson. Thanks for your kindness and time. I really mean it.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't that fix your problems??

```
Dateime dt = DateTime.Now;
dt = dt.AddSeconds(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this:

```
DateTime s = //get some datetime;
s = new DateTime(s.Year, s.Month,s.Day,s.Hour,s.Minute,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Using an extencion to DateTime:  

        public enum eTimeFragment
        {
            hours,
            minutes,
            seconds,
            milliseconds
        }
        public static DateTime ClearTimeFrom(this DateTime dateToClear, eTimeFragment etf)
        {
            DateTime dtRet = dateToClear;
            switch (etf)
            {
                case eTimeFragment.hours:
                    dtRet = dateToClear.Date;
                    break;
                case eTimeFragment.minutes:
                    dtRet = dateToClear.AddMinutes(dateToClear.Minute * -1);
                    dtRet = dtRet.ClearTimeFrom(eTimeFragment.seconds);
                    break;
                case eTimeFragment.seconds:
                    dtRet = dateToClear.AddSeconds(dateToClear.Second * -1);
                    dtRet = dtRet.ClearTimeFrom(eTimeFragment.milliseconds);
                    break;
                case eTimeFragment.milliseconds:
                    dtRet = dateToClear.AddMilliseconds(dateToClear.Millisecond * -1);
                    break;
            }
            return dtRet;

        }
```

Use like this:

Console.WriteLine (DateTime.Now.ClearTimeFrom(eTimeFragment.hours))

this has to return:
2016-06-06 00:00:00.000

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
var NewDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy")+" "+"10:15 PM")/*Add your time here*/;
```

Answer (score -2):

What's wrong with DateTime.AddSeconds method where you can add or substract seconds?

Comment: Not only that, but it doesn't sound like it answers the question anyway. I suspect the OP wants a DateTime with the same date but a specific time - which would be *relatively* hard to do just using AddSeconds.

Answer (score -2):

The best solution is:

```
currdate.AddMilliseconds(currdate.Millisecond * -1).AddSeconds(currdate.Second * -1).AddMinutes(currdate.Minute * -1).AddHours(currdate.Hour * -1);
```

Comment: At first I thought this was wrong, but it makes sense *if* you assign the result to a DateTime object. It is not the best solution though. It requires you to know the current Time portion in order to make the correct calculations, while taking the Date portion of the date and adding there is the best.

Comment: Definitely not "best". Far from readable and with repetitive usage of a magic number.

Answer (score -5):

here is a ghetto way, but it works :)

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now; //get a DateTime variable for the example
string newSecondsValue = "00";
dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:" + newSecondsValue));
```

Comment: Another ghetto way but a bit cleaner would be to just play with the seconds.  e.g. `dt.AddSeconds(0-dt.Seconds).AddSeconds(newSecondsValue)` but wouldn't recommend it.