# How to set only time part of a DateTime variable in C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have a DateTime variable:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
```

I want to change the time part of a DateTime variable. But when I tried to access time part (hh:mm:ss) these fields are readonly.

Can't I set these properties?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Use the constructor that allows you to specify the year, month, day, hours, minutes, and seconds:

```
var dateNow = DateTime.Now;
var date = new DateTime(dateNow.Year, dateNow.Month, dateNow.Day, 4, 5, 6);
```

Comment: This method can easily result on a "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime" when the day exists in the original year but not in the updated one. Simplest case being leap years. 

I would suggest something like:

`
var newYear = 2017;
var oldDate = new DateTime(2016, 2, 29);
var newDate = oldDate.AddYears(newYear - oldD.Year);
`

Notice newDate won't be 2017-2-29, which doesn't exist, but 2017-2-28 instead.

Comment: What are you talking about? There is no issue with this code.

Answer (score 28):

you can't change the DateTime object, it's immutable. However, you can set it to a new value, for example:

```
var newDate = oldDate.Date + new TimeSpan(11, 30, 55);
```

Answer (score 17):

```
date = new DateTime(date.year, date.month, date.day, HH, MM, SS);
```

Answer (score 17):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do but
 you can set the date/time to exactly what you want in a number of ways...

You can specify 12/25/2010 4:58 PM by using

```
DateTime myDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2010-12-25 16:58:00");
```

OR if you have an existing datetime construct , say 12/25/2010 (and any random time) and you want to set it to 12/25/2010 4:58 PM, you could do so like this:

```
DateTime myDate = ExistingTime.Date.AddHours(16).AddMinutes(58);
```

The `ExistingTime.Date` will be 12/25 at midnight, and you just add hours and minutes to get it to the time you want.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't possible as DateTime is immutable. The same discussion is available here: [How to change time in datetime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859248/how-to-change-time-in-datetime)