# How to add both date and time in DateTime variable

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I have two datetime variables in VB.Net

```
Dim inDt As Datetime  //contains date
Dim inTime As DateTime //contains time
```

I want to add both these variable in single DateTime variable , i didn't find any .Net function to do that.Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Is there a reason why these aren't just one variable in the first place?

Comment: Actually i am receiving them as a function argument..

Comment: Check out [how to change time in datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859248/how-to-change-time-in-datetime), that should give you a start.

Answer (score 2):

Illustrating my comment above, you can do this:

```
DateTime combinedDateTime = inDt + 
         new TimeSpan(0, inTime.Hour, inTime.Minute, inTime.Second, inTime.Millisecond);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the `Ticks` property and the `AddTicks` method:

```
Dim result As DateTime
result = inDt.AddTicks(inTime.Ticks)
```