# How to serialise DateTime with seconds displayed as 0?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have some DateTime's that will be calculated in the format: `dtDateTime.ToString("M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt")` and I want to *keep* the `ss` formatting but just set the value to zero. Example:

Before Change:

`"7/14/2014 7:34:27 AM"`

After Change:

`"7/14/2014 7:34:00 AM"`

What I have tried:

```
dtDateTime = my DateTime
TimeSpan secondsDifference = dtDateTime.Subtract(new System.DateTime(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, dtDateTime.Second)
dtDateTime = dtDateTime.Date - secondsDifference;
return dtDateTime.ToString("M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt")
```

This gives me an error, on the `dtDateTime.Subtract()` expression because this date is before 1970, when (I think) Unix Time stamping started. How can I simply set the `seconds` part of `dtDateTime` to `00`?

NB - code brevity is important. Thanks all.

Comment: [Build a new `DateTime` and hardcode the seconds.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/272ba130(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to change time in datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859248/how-to-change-time-in-datetime)

Comment: @Neolisk That SO post is what my original code was based off of (esp the `dtDateTime = dtDateTime.Date - secondsDifference;` line, but I knew there had to be a simpler way!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the purpose is to only show `00` seconds then just replace `ss` with `00`

```
dtDateTime.ToString("M/dd/yyyy h:mm:00 tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: @Habib What if we would like to **set** `00` seconds to `dt`? Here the console displays `00` but `dt` still keeps the assigned seconds...

Comment: @ironzionlion, the OP's code has `return dtDateTime.ToString...` so the OP is returning a formatted string. There should be no need to set `dt`'s seconds to zero.

Comment: @Habib thanks for your comment. I am just wondering if there would be a wait to define a `DateTime` already with a fixed value, in that case, `ss`. Is there a way to define a `DateTime` value that stays constant, even if I try `dt = dt.AddSeconds(5)`?

Comment: @ironzionlion, `DateTime` is immutable, So any change you made the object will return a new object. Therefore you can use **readonly** DateTime like: `readonly DateTime SomeDate = new DateTime(2014, 01, 01);` . It will not be a `const` but it will give you somewhat similar functionality

Answer (score 24):

```
myDate = myDate.AddSeconds(-myDate.Second)
```

Comment: Compact and simple to use

Answer (score 8):

I haven't tried it but changing the format to "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:00 tt" should work.

Answer (score 4):

You could try the following:

```
// create a new datetime based on this you have
DateTime dt = new DateTime(inputDate.Year, 
                           inputDate.Month, 
                           inputDate.Day, 
                           inputDay.Hour, 
                           inputDay.Minute, 
                           0);


// print it to the console
Console.WriteLine(t.ToString("M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"));
```

Comment: I like this solution.  It is setting the seconds property directly on declaration.