# SQL query one day off

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

I am running a SQL-Query in C# using <kbd>Dapper</kbd> & <kbd>DapperQueryBuilder</kbd>.

```
using Dapper;
using DapperQueryBuilder;
```

I use `startDate` and `endDate` as lower and upper date limit, since I am not interested in entries that are fare in past.

```
string startDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-14).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
string endDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

The query looks as following:

```
var originalData = cn.QueryBuilder($@"
            SELECT TOP 10000
               dbo.BEOLStatus_SelCol.Priority,
               dbo.BEOLStatus_SelCol.Stage,
               dbo.BEOLStatus_SelCol.Batch,
               dbo.BEOLStatus_SelCol.Product_Name,
               dbo.BEOLStatus_SelCol.DInStage
            FROM dbo.BEOLStatus_SelCol
            WHERE (((dbo.BEOLStatus_SelCol.Priority) Like {Priority})
            AND ((dbo.BEOLStatus_SelCol.Stage) Is Not Null)
            AND ((dbo.BEOLStatus_SelCol.Batch) Is Not Null)
            AND ((dbo.BEOLStatus_SelCol.Product_Name) Is Not Null)
            AND ((dbo.BEOLStatus_SelCol.DInStage) Is Not Null)
            AND ((dbo.BEOLStatus_SelCol.StageNo) Like {StageNo})
            AND ((dbo.BEOLStatus_SelCol.DInStage) >= {startDate})
            AND ((dbo.BEOLStatus_SelCol.DInStage) <= {endDate}))
            ORDER BY dbo.BEOLStatus_SelCol.Priority").Query();
```

I also tried the following one:

```
var originalData = cn.QueryBuilder($@"
            SELECT TOP 10000
               dbo.BEOLStatus_SelCol.Priority,
               dbo.BEOLStatus_SelCol.Stage,
               dbo.BEOLStatus_SelCol.Batch,
               dbo.BEOLStatus_SelCol.Product_Name,
               dbo.BEOLStatus_SelCol.DInStage
            FROM dbo.BEOLStatus_SelCol
            WHERE (((dbo.BEOLStatus_SelCol.Priority) Like {Priority})
            AND ((dbo.BEOLStatus_SelCol.Stage) Is Not Null)
            AND ((dbo.BEOLStatus_SelCol.Batch) Is Not Null)
            AND ((dbo.BEOLStatus_SelCol.Product_Name) Is Not Null)
            AND ((dbo.BEOLStatus_SelCol.DInStage) Is Not Null)
            AND ((dbo.BEOLStatus_SelCol.StageNo) Like {StageNo})
            AND ((dbo.BEOLStatus_SelCol.DInStage) Between {startDate} and {endDate}))
            ORDER BY dbo.BEOLStatus_SelCol.Priority").Query();
```

I can see 7 datasets in the database that fit the following criteria:

- `Priority`
- `StageNo`
- between `startDate` = 09.16.2022 and `endDate` = 09.30.2022

6 out of the 7 datasets get returned as expected, but one is missing.

The one dataset missing looks as following:

- `Priority` = 3
- `StageNo` = 149
- `DInStage` = 09.30.2022 (#)

*(#) actually 30.09.2022 because the database is located in Europe, but based on the other 6 datasets returning I assume it gets internally converted and seems to be working*

I figured out that if I change `endDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")` to `DateTime.Now.AddDays(+1).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")` I get the 7 datasets that I want.

`DInStage >= startDate` and `DInStage <= endDate` also seem to make sense to me.

Does anybody see where I did a mistake that causes this one day off? Why do I need to add one additional day? I notice the same behaviour when using the same query in MS Access.
I assume the same is true for `dateStart`, but I haven't specifically checked that yet.

Comment: if `DInStage` is `datetime` then you should include the time part too. Or you could just add one day, and change it from `less than or equal` to `less than`.

Comment: @iSR5 I think you are right, so I played a little bit around with it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should never convert datetime to to string, if it's a Datetime column in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out the reason:

- I thought that by using `ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")` I would be solely comparing the **Date** of `startDate`/`endDate` with `DInStage`
- But actually the **Time** is still considered during the `>=`/`<=`/`Between`

So I switched to `ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")` instead which solved the problem for me.
I am using now:

```
startDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-14).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
endDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(0).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

So I think when using this new code now I am actually using the timespan between *(lets assume for simplicity that its rn 09:00 on 30.09.2022)*:

- `startDate` = 16.09.2022 09:00:00
- `endDate` = 30.09.2022 09:00:00

So to be entirely correct I would need to set the 09:00:00 to 00:00:00/23:59:59 in order to get a 100% accurate result. But for my use case that's already close enough.
I assume it can be solved by following the provided solution found at [How to change time in DateTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859248/how-to-change-time-in-datetime), but I haven't actually verified it.